# how to separate int and str from a list in python

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a list of 1000 records in it. The list is a mixture of int values and str values for example

```
    df.head()
+-------+
|   0   |
+-------+
| asber |
| cdedg |
| hfowe |
| idcpo |
| fukvm |
| 123   |
| 456   |
| 789   |
| 012   |
+-------+
```

I want all the numerical value in one side and all categorical value in another side basically, make 2 new list  one with all numerical value and another with categorical value

Please let me know if there is a solution for this..

Answer (score 2):

As you described in the comment your number values are also in the string format.

```
valuelist = ['abc', 'xyz', '123', '456']
numberlist = list()
strlist = list()
for num in valuelist:
    if num.isdigit():
        numberlist.append(int(num)) #do type cast for conversion
    else:
        strlist.append(num)
```

now you can print or iterate both the lists based on your uses.

Comment: You may replace num with val.

Answer (score 0):

For a list,

```
lis = [1, 2, 3, 'ab', 'bc', 'ac']
import numbers
lis1 = []
lis2 = []
for i in lis:
    if isinstance(i, numbers.Integral):
        lis1.append(i)
    else:
        lis2.append(i)
```

This will output

```
lis1 = [1, 2, 3]
lis2 = ['ab', 'bc', 'ac']
```

Comment: I have an issue all my numeric values are also marked as str, in this case, what can I do?

For ex: it's not 123 but its '123'

Comment: You can do the following 
import numbers
lis1 = []
lis2 = []
for i in lis:
    try:
        if isinstance(int(i), numbers.Integral):
            lis1.append(i)
    except:
        lis2.append(i)

It tries to convert the string to int, but if it cannot be converted, as for the case of 'ab', it goes to except block. Otherwise, it checks for the integer equivalent. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
categorical = [i for i in df["0"] if not i.isdigit()]
numerical = [int(i) for i in df["0"] if i.isdigit()]
```

*Note: 
Although this looks compact, it is using 2 for loops, you can do it with single for loop like @HarshilJain's answer*